# iOS Spotlight Search - show extra app information?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, spotlight, nsuseractivity

If you search for Pixelmator or Snapseed in iOS spotlight search. It indeed shows the Apps but also write their category which is "Photography" on the right.

[image]

[image]

I am wondering how to achieve this? Nothing major but I am trying to get my head around the new 3 iOS 9 search frameworks.

You can also notice that Snapseed has it's own category which shows with a Snapseed header. How is that?

Finally, if I search for "crop", "contrast", "vignette", "selective", "brush", "transform".. Snapseed also shows up!

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

That’s not the App Store category, it’s the folder the app is in. Try it for yourself: add an app to a folder with an arbitrary name, then search for the app name. You’re seeing “Photography” there because that’s the default name for folders created with photography apps (as categorized by the App Store).

As to the appearance of its own category and the other search terms that bring it up: check out the [CoreSpotlight framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreSpotlight/Reference/CoreSpotlight_Framework/), specifically `CSSearchableItem` and the `CSSearchableIndex` that you’ll need to add it to.

Comment: Haha gosh that's a funny one. Thanks regarding the folder, well spotted. 

I will give a shot to CoreSpotlight. I just find it difficult to understand if I should be using that or NSUserActivity or maybe both.